# insert data to table 1 from table 2 while referencing table 2 and 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am building an SQL script that will assist in the automation of creating new AD accounts.

I have 3 tables relating to my question - CurrentAD, ADChanges and Worker.

The CurrentAD table will hold a list of all AD accounts and does not get cleaned out, however the worker and ADChanges tables are cleaned out and re-populated every time the script is run.

The purpose of the ADChanges table is that if we have a record in the worker table where, as an example, the surname of the user name is different but the given name and employee ID are a match to an existing record in the CurrentAD table, that row is inserted from the worker table to the ADChanges table, then deleted from the worker table.

This is the first time I have done any SQL scripting but everything seems to be working except this one block of code:

```
INSERT INTO ADChanges (sn, givenName, employeeID)
SELECT Worker.sn, Worker.givenName, Worker.employeeID
FROM Worker,
CurrentAD
WHERE Worker.sn NOT LIKE CurrentAD.sn AND Worker.employeeID LIKE CurrentAD.employeeID
OR Worker.givenName LIKE CurrentAD.givenName AND Worker.sn LIKE CurrentAD.sn AND Worker.ou LIKE           CurrentAD.ou
OR Worker.givenName NOT LIKE CurrentAD.givenName AND Worker.employeeID LIKE CurrentAD.employeeID
GO
```

The above code is what is supposed to be able to distinguish the changes from the new entries however it doesn't do this - nor does it throw me an error. I believe it might be because there are 3 tables involved but again as this is my first time I don't event know where to start.

Everything I have found on the internet thus far tells me how to join data from 2 tables to a third which isn't what I need to do.

Any help would be appreciated! I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What do you mean that you don't need to "join data from 2 tables to a third"?  Joining 5 tables can be expressed logically as `( ( ( table1 JOIN table2 ) JOIN table3 ) JOIN table4 ) JOIN table5`.

Comment: I suggest that you start by explicitly grouping your WHERE conditions with brackets () so that there is no ambiguity with what your statement is returning.

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend using ANSI JOIN syntax for clarity.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server expert, but in Oracle, it's not a good idea to use `LIKE` when you don't want to use wildcards.  Is this the case in SQL Server also?  I'd wager it is.  If so, you should be using `=` instead.

Comment: @Zach - I went with your suggestion and that seems to have fixed it! I had tried several workarounds but not tried that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is explicitly wrap your various WHERE clauses in parentheses so you're sure you know what you're searching on. I'm sure there's documentation out there around how exactly SQL does precedence in WHERE clauses, but best practice suggests you just wrap them in parentheses so you're absolutely sure.

Secondly, if you're not doing wildcard lookups, use equality operators rather than LIKE operators. I think you'll end up with the same query plan in this case, but it will help greatly to deobfuscate your code.

Thirdly, there are a lot of OR clauses in here that you're trying to evaluate at once, which can cause SQL to get a bad query plan. You might be better off breaking out the different cases (I think I see three in here, I may be wrong) into separate statements. That will make it clearer to read, debug, and for SQL to optimize.

An example of one of these cases might look like this (using joins rather than cross product with filtering)

```
insert into ADChanges (sn, GivenName, EmployeeID)
select w.sn, w.givenName, w.employeeID
from Worker w
inner join CurrentAd c
    on w.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
        and (w.sn != c.sn or
             w.GivenName != c.GivenName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Xedni - I implemented the sample code that you supplied which doesn't seem to have worked.

My apologies for being clueless on you here, but I'm curious to know why we would use a join to perform this function at all?

I just want to reiterate in case I wasn't clear earlier, I want to move a record from table 2 to table 1 based on the conditions that the data in table 2 and table 3 do/do not match if that makes sense?

Comment: It's a little hard to picture without seeing the DDL of the tables and some sample data, but when you say "... that the data in table 2 and table 3 do/do not match", that sounds like you're describing a join to me. I don't see a way to do the comparison of one table to the contents of another without a join.

I would still suggest listing out all the distinct cases you want to happen, and then write a separate, simplified, and clear insert for each case. If you want to post table defs and some sample data, I could try to help with the join specifics.